# How can I iterate array with type NSString and type int and get NSString element with lowest int?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsstring

I have some array with employees and their salary. I need to iterate the array and output one employee with the lowest salary in the array.

```
//array
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray<Employee *> *employees;

-(void) addEmployeeWithName:(NSString *)employeesName andLastName:(NSString *) employeesLastName andSalary:(int)employeesSalary;

//implementation of method
-(void) addEmployeeWithName:(NSString *)employeesName andLastName:(NSString *)employeesLastName andSalary:(int)employeesSalary
{
    Employee *myEmp =[[Employee alloc] initWithFirstName:employeesName lastName:employeesLastName salary:employeesSalary];

    [self.employees addObject:myEmp];
}

//In main() function something like this:
Employee *emp1 = [[Employee alloc] initWithFirstName:@"Bob"   lastName:@"Lan" salary:1];
Employee *emp2 = [[Employee alloc] initWithFirstName:@"Ivan" lastName:@"Pal" salary:22];
```

Comment: I`ve tried to do this with getting back the smallest value, and after this I need to get NSString element. At this point I`m dont understand how I can do this.

Comment: Update your question with your current attempt to solve the problem. Include details of what issue you are having with that code.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight forward question, though I agree with rmaddy you could've easily found a solution with a simple google query-- so just a note that you should learn how to google well, because that is one of the best skills you need

What you should do is something called fast enumeration

```
int lowestSalary = INT_MAX;
Employee *lowestSalariedEmployee;
for( Employee *employee in employees )
{
  if( [employee salary] < lowestSalary )
  {
    lowestSalary = [employee salary];
    lowestSalariedEmployee = employee;
  }
}

//at this point, lowestSalariedEmployee will be a reference to your employee object with the lowest salary
```

EDIT: saw your comment about how you're confused how to get the "string element"

You'll need to reference your `Employee` class, and find the name of your "name" `@property`, which should be a string